# Accessing DOM Elements using CEFSharp in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am working on a small project based on `CEFSharp` in `C#`.

I want to know the procedure to access `DOM` Elements using `CEFSharp` in `C#`. I have all initial things setup already, just need to access the elements. I know how to do this with the built-in web Browser of `C#` but I cannot find any proper information about doing this with `CEFSharp`.

I am using the following line of code to access the `DOM` element of the `webpage` in a button click listener (separate class than browser class).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{brow.chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('q').value='Hello';");
}
```

where brow=CEF browser class object, chromeBrowser=browser instance

With the above code modified like ("alert('My Message')"), I can get an alert message easily with the `JavaScript`, no problem with that, but I want to access a specific element of `DOM`, and here nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the answer by myself, just a slight change. Hope it helps someone else too

```
brow.chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='Hello';");
```

It was a small typo in javascript line . I wrote [0] in the above syntax and everything worked fine. The textfield on the webpage got filled with my text (Hello) after my button click.

Comment: Well, your answer uses JavaScript. Is there any way to access the DOM via C# only?

Comment: @sam I think, the built in web browser of c# can be used instead of cef sharp.

Comment: Your are right, but the web browser control uses MShtml which is InternetExplorer which is not an option for my scenario..

Comment: The WebView2 uses chromium now  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/